# Indenting changed after I re-installed Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I edit C# file in Visual Studio 2010, it looks ok, but when I open it in another IDE or push to github, I notice that indenting is wrong. It happened after I reinstalled Visual Studio.

Any idea how put this on the line again? I do not remember changing any indenting options in previous installation, and I definitely didn't do anything to it this time either.

**UPDATE:**

By wrong I mean this (faked, since it cannot if copy/pasted it gets ok):

```
     _req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri(_options["url"]));
     _req.Method = _options["method"];
// disable buffering (this only works for ClientHttp version)
     //_req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; // causes silent crash on Mac OS X 10.8.x
```

in Visual Studio it looks ok. Basically any new line that I add (that didn't exist in files created in previous installation), I get weird indenting.

Comment: could you define 'wrong' please?

Comment: Ctrl-K + Ctrl-D auto-format the file, does that help?

Comment: Are you talking about the spacing - tab spaces. Are you using tabs or spaces? What were you using before?

Comment: I'm not native to Visual Studio, so not sure what it does use by default. I'm using defaults. And Ctrl-K + Ctrl-D doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should always set your editor to indent using spaces and not tabs, but I'm not sure VS allows that.

Comment: Why so? I always preferred tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in your previous installation of VS you have a different settings for your tabs.
Now, the reinstall resetted everything to the default settings.

Check the menu `Tools, ->Options, ->Text Editor, ->C#, Tabs`
and try with different settings

Comment: Thanks :) Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs > Keep Tabs - made it. Note: if you are there and you are not of Visual Studio origin, check 'Show all settings', or you won't see 'Text Editor' options.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the automatic formatting of text in Visual Studio by going to Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C#.

There you can change the way indentation is done in the Tabs submenu and in --> Formatting --> Indentation.